# How to use the OpenCV 2.4 static libraries with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm trying to set up OpenCV 2.4 as follows:

- I've downloaded and extracted the precompiled package to `C:\OpenCV240`.
- In Visual Studio, I've added `C:\OpenCV240\build\include` as an additional include directory.
- Furthermore, I've added `C:\OpenCV240\build\x86\vc10\staticlib` as an additional library directory.
- And I've specified all available .lib files as additional dependencies.

When I compile my "Hello World" program (which compiles just fine when using the DLLs), I get a lot error messages like this:

> 1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in opencv_core240d.lib(matrix.obj)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you need to specify linking against the static C runtime library in your program.

If OpenCV linked against the static CRT and you use the dynamic one, you get these types of redefinition errors.

To change this setting, open your project's Properties and go to `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation`.

Change `Runtime Library` from `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` to `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`.  Do the same for your other configurations, using the non-Debug variant where appropriate.

Comment: Does this have any side-effects or is it save to do so?

Comment: It's safe to do this, in fact you *need* to have all libraries linked together using the same version of the CRT.  However the decision as to whether you want to use static vs dynamic libraries is not always easy.